# In WPF, how can I animate different objects with different storyboard simultaneously?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

Suppose I have two animate methods AnimateHorizontally and AnimateVertically like this

```
public void AnimateHorizontally(FrameworkElement element, double XMoveStart, double XMoveEnd, int milli)
        {
            BackEase eEase = new BackEase();
            Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
            DoubleAnimation daX = new DoubleAnimation(XMoveStart, XMoveEnd, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, milli)));
            daX.EasingFunction = eEase;
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(daX, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Left)"));
            sb.Children.Add(daX);
            element.BeginStoryboard(sb);
        }

public void AnimateVertically(FrameworkElement element, double YMoveStart, double YMoveEnd, int milli)
        {
            ElasticEase eEase = new ElasticEase();
            Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
            DoubleAnimation daY = new DoubleAnimation(YMoveStart, YMoveEnd, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, milli)));
            daY.EasingFunction = eEase;
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(daY, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)"));
            sb.Children.Add(daY);
            element.BeginStoryboard(sb);
        }
```

When I apply it on an object A, it moves horizontally from XMoveStart and XMoveEnd. If I have an object B, and I want object B to apply ElasticEase and move vertically.

The animation on object A and B should start simultaneously and smoothly, how can I do that?

Simply by calling

```
AnimateVertically(A)
AnimateHorizontally(B)
```

It doesn't work that smooth and it seems that they are not simultaneous. Anyone can help? I don't have to use Storyboard, if there are some other animation methods which do the job, I can also use them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You need simply to place multiple Animations in one Storyboard and set the TargetName-Property of the Animations:

Here a sample-storyboard. Notice the TargetName-Properties:

```
 <Storyboard x:Name="FromMainToBack">
  <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ScaleContainerGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY">
    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0.8"/>
    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="0.8"/>
    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="1"/>
  </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
  <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ScaleContainerGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX">
    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0.8"/>
    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="0.8"/>
    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="1"/>
  </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>


  <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.2" Duration="0:0:0.5" From="0" To="90" Storyboard.TargetName="planeProjectionMain" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationY">
    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
      <BackEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
  </DoubleAnimation>
  <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.7" Duration="0:0:0.5" From="270" To="360" Storyboard.TargetName="planeProjectionBack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationY">
    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
      <BackEase Amplitude="0" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
  </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```